# How to use view bag value inside jquery code in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I try to get view bag value for use inside jquery code and razor.I use this code :

```
 <script>   
    var UI=  @ViewBag.uniqid;     
    </script>
```

but get error.
how to fix this?

Comment: post the error you are getting?

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'

Comment: try `var UI =  '@ViewBag.uniqid';`

Comment: Kartikeya Khosla : OK .This is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `@ViewBag` as shown below.

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Similarly, you can also use `@TempData` with a condition as shown below:

```
@if (TempData["message"] != null)
{
    <div class="text-danger">@TempData["message"]</div>
}
```

For more information please have a look at [[ASP.NET MVC ] How to Pass Data From a Controller to a View](https://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/mvc-data-controller-view/).